# Erro em tempo de execução: 9 - subscrito fora do intervalo 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

oi! eu estou tendo problemas com esse erro. credito que eh algum problema nos dados q inseri, mas nao consigo arrumar.

```
     Calcul des cumuls annuels sur l'année hydrologique (1er septembre au 31 aout)

  For k = 1 To nbannees - 1
     For j = 1 To 12
         PluieAnnHy(k) = PluieAnnHy(k) + PluieMens(12 * (k - 1) + 8 + j)
         ETPAnnHy(k) = ETPAnnHy(k) + ETPMens(12 * (k - 1) + 8 + j)
         TemperAnnHy(k) = TemperAnnHy(k) + TemperMens(12 * (k - 1) + 8 + j)
         DebitAnnHy(k) = DebitAnnHy(k) + DebitMens(12 * (k - 1) + 8 + j)
          If dataneige_exist = True Then NeigeAnnHy(k) = NeigeAnnHy(k) + 
  NeigeMens((12 * (k - 1) + 8 + j))
  Next
  TemperAnnHy(k) = TemperAnnHy(k) / 12
  DebitAnnHy(k) = DebitAnnHy(k) / 12
```

Answer (score 1):

O que observo primeiramente é que o for interno não possuia o seu respectivo next
tente o código abaixo.

```
         ' Calcul des cumuls annuels sur l'année hydrologique (1er septembre au 31 aout)

  For k = 1 To nbannees - 1
     For j = 1 To 12
         PluieAnnHy(k) = PluieAnnHy(k) + PluieMens(12 * (k - 1) + 8 + j)
         ETPAnnHy(k) = ETPAnnHy(k) + ETPMens(12 * (k - 1) + 8 + j)
         TemperAnnHy(k) = TemperAnnHy(k) + TemperMens(12 * (k - 1) + 8 + j)
         DebitAnnHy(k) = DebitAnnHy(k) + DebitMens(12 * (k - 1) + 8 + j)
          If dataneige_exist = True Then
            NeigeAnnHy(k) = NeigeAnnHy(k) + NeigeMens((12 * (k - 1) + 8 + j))
          End If
    Next j
  Next k

  TemperAnnHy(k) = TemperAnnHy(k) / 12
  DebitAnnHy(k) = DebitAnnHy(k) / 12
```

Comment: A utilização de `Option Explicit` ajuda a evitar este tipo de erro.